# Building a navigation with a search result webpart

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, kql

I'm trying to set up a top level site that displays every Project site, creating a basic navigation. To achieve this I used a Search Result Webpart with a custom query, providing me with the correct results:

```
    Path:"{\Site.URL}/*/"
    contentclass:STS_Web 
    WebTemplate:PROJECTSITE
```

However, sites with the correct WebTemplate may become subsites of the Project sites in the future:

> /Project1/Subproject1

These subprojects are not supposed to be shown in my navigation, is there any way to exclude them and all future subprojects without hardcoding the names?

Comment: If you wanna avoid showing any subsites and just like to return sitecollections, switch content class to contentclass=STS_Site.

Comment: I do want to show subsites, just not below the first level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control the depth with the UrlDepth property.

So try to change your syntax to something like this:

`Path:{Site.URL} UrlDepth=1`

See tip 2 on this blog.

[Display a Sub Site list using a Content Search Web Part](https://exploringsp2013.wordpress.com/2014/01/27/display-a-sub-site-list-using-a-content-search-web-part/)

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! Is there some kind of documentation for the property filters that I am unable to find?

Comment: Well, i think that the overall documentation is really poor. The sites i tend to use is https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee558911.aspx and https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj683123.aspx and https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219630.aspx for managed properties reference.

Comment: Url Depth is mentioned here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn169052.aspx#sp15_example_2_ranking

Comment: Alright, thats pretty much what I have been using. Do you know a way to set a dynamic UrlDepth? I may be reusing the navigation on different site collections on a "higher" depth, this solution forces me to change it manualy for each collection.